# Vertical Navbar should collapse when clicked anywhere other than the bar-icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a verticalNavbar(having a bar-icon) which is based on toggle so when one clicks it toggles out(opens up) and clicks again it togglesin(closes). but however I want the navbar to toggle in(close) when user clicks anywhere on the web page other than the bar-icon(on verticalNavbar) - given that it was opened else the page click should not do nothing. I am finding it difficult to manage with jquery toggle, here's my code

```js
        $('.bar-icon').on("click", function(){
            $( ".left-side" ).toggleClass('wdt80');
            $( ".left-side" ).toggleClass('wdt210');
            $('.left-side-inner').toggle('fast');
            $( ".left-side" ).toggleClass("shadow");
            $('.overlay').toggle();
        });
```

```html
<div class="bar-icon">
    <a ><img src="///_baricon_img.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

My Solution -

```js
// closing vertical navbar - while opened
           $('.page').on("click",function(){
                if ($('.left-side-inner').is(':visible')) {
                            $( ".left-side" ).toggleClass('wdt210');     
                            $( ".left-side" ).toggleClass('wdt80');
                            $('.left-side-inner').toggle('fast');
                            $( ".left-side" ).toggleClass("shadow");
                            $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
                            // $('.overlay').toggle();                
                } 
            });
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet for what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael, you could `addClass` instead of using `toggleClass`, also comparing if something has a class to prevent adding repeated classes, so you could do something like this:

```
$('.bar-icon').on("click", function(){
    if($( ".left-side" ).hasClass('wdt210'){
        $( ".left-side" ).addClass('wdt210');
        $('.left-side-inner').show('fast');
        $( ".left-side" ).addClass("shadow");
        $('.overlay').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: it helped some way :), Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.click` or window.click to achieve this.

```
$(window).click(function(){
//Close menu
});
$(document).on('click', function(){
//Close menu
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class to navbar when it open and remove same when it is close. Use same class.

```
$(document).click(function() {
   if($('.bar-icon').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.bar-icon').trigger('click');  
   }
});
```